# Why are my Python queries through mysql.connector to a WordPress db failing sometimes?

Tags: python, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Python mysql.connector to connect to a WordPress database and retrieve Woocommerce sales information to create a sales report. Below is some of the code I have written to loop through each line of a cursor object and retrieve the information I want about each order.

````
query = ('SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = (%s)')
cursor.execute(query, (this_order,))
for line in cursor:
    if '_billing_first_name' in line:
        first_name = line[3]
        
    if '_billing_last_name' in line:
        last_name = line[3]

    if '_paid_date' in line:
        sale_date = line[3]
        transaction_date = datetime.strptime(sale_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        transaction_year = transaction_date.year
        transaction_month = transaction_date.month
    else:
        transaction_month = None 
        transaction_year = None
        
    if '_order_total' in line:
        order_total = line[3].replace('.*', '')
        order_total = int(float(order_total))

        # Increment total sales by order total
        total_sales += order_total

        print(this_order, first_name, last_name, product_name, '$', order_total, transaction_month, transaction_year, '\n') ```
````

This code gave me an error about `transaction_month` being `undefined` until I added the `else` statement that set `transaction_month` and `transaction_year` to `None` if the string `'_paid_date'` was not found in the `cursor` object. I didn't have that originally because I couldn't imagine that every WC transaction wouldn't have this information included. But sure enough, once I added it as a failsafe, the code worked. Some orders are being printed out with `'None None'` where they should have `'10 2020'` or `'11 2020'` for month and year.

If I print out the entire cursor object for an order with missing dates, I can see that the field `'_paid_date'` has an entry just like every other one. Yet my query of the db failed to retrieve it. I am not having any similar problem getting any of the other values I am looking for, like customer names, order totals, order id, etc.

Why would this happen? Is my query simply failing sometimes, or is something else happening?

Comment: Can you provide a sample row which has _paid_date set but doesn't return it when queried?